# Convert Map to String with double quotes escaped using Gson

Tags: java, json, gson, escaping

I have the following `Map` :

```java
import java.util.Map;

Map<String, Object> myMap = Map.of(
    "key1", "value1",
    "key2", Map.of(
        "key2-1", "value2-1",
        "key2-2", 22
    )
));
```

I'm trying to convert this to the following `String` using [`Gson`](https://github.com/google/gson) :

```
String expected = // ???
System.out.println(expected);
{\"key1\":\"value1\",\"key2\":{\"key2-1\":\"value2-1\",\"key2-2\":22}}
```

(note that double quotes when printing are escaped).

As of now, to achieve this, I'm doing :

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;

String myMapAsJsonString = new Gson().toJson(myMap);
String myMapAsJsonStringWithDoubleQuotesEscaped = myMapAsJsonString.replace("\"", "\\\"");
```

But I'm pretty sure the second line can be replaced by something else, and that I can only use `Gson` to achieve the escaping I want?

Any idea would be greatly appreciated !

Comment: Why do you need this if the generated string is not a JSON at all?

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand your comment. First, I have converted my `Map` to a JSON, and then escaped the double quotes. The result is a String containing a JSON with double quotes escaped.

Comment: The outcome you're expecting to get is clearly not a JSON (I would call it JSON-look-pretending data), and even not a JSON literal (what you meaning by word "string") just because it falls into illegal syntax. Take any JSON validation tool and check why. If you're going to make it a "string" like this, why are you replacing quotes with backslashed quotes with replaceAll that cannot handle inner strings, rather than re-serializing the first JSON document to a string over again to get a proper JSON "string" enclosed in proper `"` delimiters?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Ok, I got it ! I just did `new Gson().toJson(myMapAsJsonString)` once again and it seems it have escaped the double quotes. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Thanks to [@fluffy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12232870/fluffy))

Instead of doing :

```java
String myMapAsJsonStringWithDoubleQuotesEscaped = myMapAsJsonString.replace("\"", "\\\"");
```

I've just reserialized the JSON string once again :

```java
import com.google.gson.Gson;

String myMapAsJsonString = new Gson().toJson(myMap);
// reserialize once again with toJson method
String myMapAsJsonStringWithDoubleQuotesEscaped = new Gson().toJson(myMapAsJsonString);
```

And got the correct result I was expecting :

```java
System.out.println(myMapAsJsonStringWithDoubleQuotesEscaped);
```

prints :

```
"{\"key1\":\"value1\",\"key2\":{\"key2-1\":\"value2-1\",\"key2-2\":22}}"
```

Comment: No, it does not print that because Gson does not produce illegal JSON documents whereas yours is illegal. Again, the second `toJson` produces a _string_, so that it cannot produce what you provided, but it provides: `"{\"key1\":...}"` (note the quote characters at the begin and the end of the result literal).

Comment: @fluffy you're right, bad copy-paste, I've fixed it. Thanks again for your help 